# RabbitMQ consumer as Windows Worker

Tags: c#, docker, rabbitmq, easynetq

Trying to make a `containerised` windows service using docker to consume messages from `rabbitmq` queues. 
I am also using `EasyNetQ` client to connect with RabbitMQ.

However it is failing with `Persistent` Channel timed out exception

> > The operation requested on PersistentChannel timed out

Here is my code for Executing the consumer

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
          try
          {
              using (var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost;username=guest;password=guest"))
              {
                 bus.Receive("Queue", msg => msg.Add<CustomModel>(m =>
                 {
                   _logger.LogInformation("Received Message: {0}, {1}", m.Prop1, m.Prop2);}));
                 }
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);               
              }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               _logger.LogError(ex.InnerException?.ToString());
           }
     }
}
```

I am not really sure what could be causing the timeout? Anybody have similar issue?

Comment: Is the connection string from your example the same with the one from your Windows service? I am asking this because this exception may appear if you are not using the correct host/username/password in the connection string.

Comment: That is just an example but in my actual programme I have username and password also in the connection string. Will update queustions thanks.

Comment: Maybe the user doesn't have the permissions to access the wanted virtual host..

Comment: Makes sense, do you suggest i need to grant access to Windows Service?

Comment: The user from the connection string needs to have permissions to access the virtual host, you can find more details [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html) about the permissions/authorization.

Comment: Its strange as I can post and receive message using a console app.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/b1719z/how_could_connect_my_application_to_rabbitmq_in/) can help. Telling to the Docker container to forward the default (5672) port.

Comment: ok thanks will look at the solution. Just to confirm so rabbitmq is also running as a docker instance.

Comment: You need to replace localhost with the IP of the machine where the RabbitMQ is running , since on the windows worker container localhost will be resolved to the worker container itself.